# macOS 13.2.1 setting menu is superslow for MacBook Pro 2017

Tags: network, wifi, bug

After updating for macOS 13, the menu settings, when I want to change network settings, is super slow. For example, when I try to change the network proxy settings for a WiFi network it took 10 clicks and more than 30 seconds to perform the desired action. Sometimes, I have to force close the Settings app and reopen it.

Sometimes Notes app is slow too.

Windowserver use like 20-40% of CPU loads.

Comment: Start by booting into Safe Mode. This will boot without 3rd party apps or drivers loading.  If things return to normal, then it’s likely something that was installed that is causing the problem.  Start there and report back with an [edit] to your question.